# Proof that $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous ($\delta-\epsilon$)?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I wanted to know if there's anything wrong with my proof below.

$f(x)=x^2$ and let $c$ be an arbitrary constant.

$\mathbf1.$ 
First, $0<|x-c|<\delta$

Now,
$|x^2-c^2|=|x+c||x-c|\le(|x|+|c|)|x-c|<\epsilon\Rightarrow|x-c|<{\epsilon\over|x|+|c|}\le{\epsilon\over|x|}\Rightarrow|x-c|<{\epsilon\over|x|}$

So we have $\delta={\epsilon\over|x|}$ that satisfies the necessary condition: if $0<|x-c|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(c)|=|x^2-c^2|<\epsilon$

$c$ was arbitrary, so we can see that $f(x)$ is continuous, except not necessarily at $x=0$.

We need to make sure that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous at $x=0$, since in the previous section, we can't have $|x|=0$.

$\mathbf2.$ For $x=0$,

$0<|x-0|<\delta\Rightarrow|x|<\delta$ , and

$|x^2-0|=|x^2|=(|x|)^2<\epsilon\Rightarrow|x|<\sqrt\epsilon$

So we have $\delta=\sqrt\epsilon$ , and thus we can see that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous at $x=0$ as well.

From conclusions drawn at the end of $\mathbf1$ and $\mathbf2$, we have shown that $f(x)$ is continuous on $x\in\mathbb R$

I just started learning about $\epsilon-\delta$. If you spot any error(s), please let me know how to correct them. Thanks!

Comment: This should help -https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2118059/135775

Answer (score 12):

You have probably seen an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof before, so writing a basic proof won't tell you anything new. So I will write how I *think* when I prove something like this. First off, the definition:

> $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous at $x_0$ if, for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that for any $c$ with $|x_0-c|<\delta$, we have $|f(x_0)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. $f$ is continuous if it is continuous at every real number.

In terms of how we write the proof, that means we're *given* arbitrary $x_0, \epsilon$, and we must find a $\delta$ that works. You have already deduced that $|f(x_0)-f(c)| = |x_0^2 - c^2| = |x_0-c|\cdot |x_0+c|$, which is good. We will need that. Why will we need that? Because the first factor of that factorisation is the one thing we have real control over: it will be smaller than $\delta$, and we are free to choose $\delta$. We want the entire expression to be smaller than whatever $\epsilon$ we're given, so the only thing left is to make sure that the second factor, $|x_0+c|$ doesn't ruin things too much.

The standard thing to do to gain control over that term is to declare that whatever happens, I will never choose a $\delta$ which is larger than $1$ (nothing special about $1$ here, I might as well choose $1000$ or $\pi$, but I like $1$). That forces $c$ to be rather close to $x_0$, which means explicitly that $|x_0+c|<2|x_0| + 1$.

Thus, as long as we vow to never pick $\delta$ larger than $1$, that gives us
$$
|f(x_0)-f(c)| = |x_0^2 - c^2| = |x_0-c|\cdot |x_0+c|<\delta(2|x_0| + 1)\tag{*}
$$
Note that we haven't really picked a $\delta$ yet, we just know that whichever one we pick, as long as it's smaller than or equal to $1$, the inequality $\text{(*)}$ holds, which is good. Why is that good? Because ultimately, we want to be able to choose a $\delta$ so that the left-hand side is smaller than the $\epsilon$ we're given. This is easily achieved by picking a $\delta$ that makes the *right-hand* side of $\text{(*)}$ no bigger than $\epsilon$.

Thus we have
$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon &\geq \delta(2|x_0| + 1)\\
\delta&\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2|x_0| + 1}\tag{**}\end{align}
$$
So, which $\delta$ do we actually pick? Well, we vowed never to choose a $\delta$ greater than $1$. While under that vow, we found that any $\delta$ which fulfills $\text{(**)}$ works. Thus, if we pick exactly $\frac{\epsilon}{2|x_0| + 1}$, as long as that's smaller than $1$, and we pick $1$ if $\frac{\epsilon}{2|x_0| + 1}>1$, then we really have fulfilled both requirements, and we are done.

Explicitly, this means that we have picked $\delta = \min\left(1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{2|x_0| + 1}\right)$.

Comment: This is the proof I just came up with after someone told me that I can't have $\delta$ depend on $x$, and was gonna do a re-post to see if it's acceptable. Thanks for the thorough explanations!

Comment: @orchid $\delta$ is allowed to depend on what I call $x_0$ in this answer. However, it is not allowed to depend on $c$, since it is $\delta$ that limits what $c$ can be (both of these can be called $x$ if you want, as long as you're consistent). If you can find a $\delta$ which doesn't depend on $x_0$, then the function is called _uniformly_ continuous.

Comment: Wait, in your post, shouldn't $\delta$ depend on $c$ instead of $x_0$?

$|x_0-c|<\delta$ ; if we set $\delta\le1$ then $|x_0-c|<1\rightarrow|x_0+c|<2|c|+1$ , no? Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: Continuing from above, I can then have in my scratch work like this:

$|x_0+c||x_0-c|<|x_0-c|(1+2|c|)<\epsilon\Rightarrow|x_0-c|<\epsilon/(1+2|c|)$

So then in my proof I can let $\delta=\epsilon/(1+2|c|)$

Comment: @orchid No, I am checking whether $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. That means that when the time comes for me to find $\delta$, I have some fixed $x_0$ and $\epsilon$ at my disposal to help me. Then I pick a $\delta$, and once I do that, I collect _all the numbers_ $c$ such that $|x_0-c|<\delta$, and I check for each and every one of them whether $|f(x_0) - f(c)|<\epsilon$. If that's true, then we're done, and if it's not, then I either picked a too large $\delta$, or it's impossible.

Comment: But of course, if you want to swap the roles of $x_0$ and $c$, you're allowed to do that. Just be careful to do it everywhere and consistently. I might have read your question wrong in that respect, and if so, I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Oh, I was confused because I was using them backwards throughout, and instead of $|x_0-c|<\delta$ I had $|c-x_0|<\delta$ which are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First error: $0<|x-c|<\delta$. You wrote that $c$ is “an arbitrary constant”. But what is $x$? And what is $\delta$?

Second error: you write that $(|x|+|c|)|x-c|<\epsilon$. What is $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

Here a correct redaction (I know it's not your question, but it's to give you an example) :

You need to prove that $$\forall a\in \mathbb R,\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0: \forall x\in \mathbb R, |x-a|<\delta\implies |x^2-a^2|<\varepsilon.$$

So let $a\in \mathbb R$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. You have that $$|x^2-a^2|=|x-a||x+a|.$$
Since we are interested in neighborhood of $a$, we can consider $\delta<1$, (i.e. $x\in [a-1,a+1]$). So when $x\in [a-1,a+1]$, you have that $|x+a|\leq \max\{|2a-1|,|2a+1|\}$. Let denote $M=\max\{|2a-1|,|2a+1|\}$. If $\varepsilon\geq M$, set $\delta=1$ and you'll have $$|x-a|<\delta\implies |x^2-a^2|=|x-a|\varepsilon\leq \varepsilon $$

and if $\varepsilon<M$, then set $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{M}$, and you'll have

$$|x^2-a^2|=|x-a||x+a|\leq M|x-a|\leq M\frac{\varepsilon}{M}=\varepsilon.$$

In other word, if $\varepsilon>0$ is unspecified, set $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{M}\}$, and you'll have that $$|x-a|<\delta\implies |x^2-a^2|\leq \varepsilon,$$
what prove the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest error in my opinion:
$$\delta={\epsilon\over|x|}$$
You may **not** take $\delta$ to depend on $x$, but only on $c$ (the value that $x$ tends to) and on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh, my bad! That was a mistake, I realize. I should have picked out a value for $\delta$ and found an expression of x in terms of c first.

Comment: You can use $|x+c| = |(x-c)+2c| \leq |x-c| + 2|c| < \delta + 2|c|$ and then make sure $\delta<|c|$ to get $<3|c|$.

Comment: So then $|x-c||x+c|<(3|c|)|x-c|<\epsilon\rightarrow|x-c|<{\epsilon\over(3|c|)}$

and then we let $\delta = {\epsilon\over3|c|}\$



|x^2-c^2| = |x-c||x+c| < (\delta)(3|c|) = ({\epsilon\over3|c|})(3|c|) = \epsilon$

Is this correct?

Comment: You mean that you take $\delta < \epsilon/(3|c|)$? And since you already have taken $\delta < |c|$ you should thus have $\delta < \min(\epsilon/(3|c|), |c|)$.

Comment: As long as $\delta < |c|$, isn't it fine to have $\delta = \epsilon/(3|c|)$?

Comment: Yes, it is, but it's easiest to just say $\delta < \min(\epsilon/(3|c|), |c|)$.